# How do I find which style is affecting the control appearce in WPF

Tags: wpf, styles

If you have lot of styles affecting the same control, what is the best way to determine the style in use at run time. It seems very hard to find the right style affecting at design time as the style and the brushes in use could be applied at different levels.

For example: I have a datagrid which is made of rows and cells. When I hover over a cell, it affects border thickness ( from 0,0,1,1 to 0,0,1,0) and I cannot seem to find which style is affecting the change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use [Snoop](https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf) to debug my application at run time. It will tell you what the current property value is, and where its coming from (although sometimes it's a bit vague, such as just saying "Inherited" instead of what it's inherited by).

But typically you can only set a `Style` to a single value, and that can only be `BasedOn` at most one style, so I don't run into this problem that often.

Another useful resource is the [Dependency Property Precedence List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx#listing) to help diagnose which values take precedence over others in the event that the same property is set in multiple places.

Comment: I am using Snoop, but all it says is derived from ParentTemplate, which is not much helpful in this case

Comment: Looks like there is no way, other than eliminating styles one by one.

Comment: The Dependency Property Precedence List link is dead

Comment: @JoaoMilasch Thanks, I fixed it

Comment: And if you're new to Snoop, you should check out the Ctrl+Shift tip for inspecting elements: https://www.cplotts.com/2011/02/10/snoop-tips-tricks-1-ctrl-shift-mouse-over/